# Finding the final state of the $1$ dimensional "split the twos" automata

Tags: algorithms, cellular-automata

This problem is from a coding competition ( [Website Here](https://blogs.iteso.mx/acm/primera-fase-gran-premio-de-mexico-centroamerica/) ) in Mexico that does not provide solutions and has me stuck.

Consider the following automata:

Every state $B_k$ is an array of fixed length $n$ such that $B_k[i]$ an integer for all $0\leq i \leq n-1$

The state $B_k$ can be obtained from the state $B_{k-1}$ as follows:

$B_k[i] = B_{k-1}[i] + C_{k-1}[i]$ if $B_{k-1}[i] < 2$ and $B_k[i] = B_{k-1}[i] - 2 + C_{k-1}[i]$ if $B_k[i] \geq 2$.

The quantity $C_{k}[i]$ is defined as the number of entries $B_k[i-1],B_k[i+1]$ that are at least $2$. (If $i$ is equal to $0$ or $n-1$ then $C_k[i]$ can be at most $1$).

We are given an arbitrary initial state $B_0$ of size $n\leq 10^6$ where each $B_0[i]$ is $0,1$ or $2$.

---

So in coloquial terms the only thing this automaton does is send a $1$ to the left and right if one of the entries is $2$ or more.

It is not hard to see that after a finite number of steps $B_k$ becomes invariant ( Because $B_k[0]$ cannot be equal to $2$ an infinite number of times we can use induction on $n$ for example) .

I would like to find the final state, something along the speed of $\mathcal O(n\log(n))$ seems to be required for the solution to pass.

Original statement:

[image]

Comment: If I could write the iteration as some sort of multiplication in an algebra by an element $\sigma$ and calculate $\sigma^M$ with logarithmic exponentiation that would be great but I have not been able to.

Comment: I do not know how to reference it since it's ran in a buggy server that needs a username

Comment: You are given the entire array $C_0$ and along with it you are given $n$.

Comment: Could you edit the question to say something like, "this is the problem 3, 'Permuting and adding up' in Gran Premio México 2018 Fecha 1"? By the way, I cannot find the problem on the website you provided. That might be caused by I knew almost nothing about Spanish and Google translation of website pages is not perfect yet.

Comment: actually my definition for the automaton is slightly wrong

Comment: @Apass.Jack No, the reason you can't find it is that the website sucks and the problems are behind a different server that requires a username and password that I do not have. However luckily one of the people from my university solved it. Also, the original statement of the problem is more confusing.

Comment: Is your definition still wrong? If so, I would suggest correcting it before someone attempts to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus The definition is fine except for the fact that the sequence can sometimes stop being ternary, i'll add it shortly

Comment: Your definition of $C_k$ is still wrong.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I don't think it is, the idea is that if an entry is $2$ or more then it sends a $1$ to the left and it sends a $1$ to the right. Edit: I guess the new definition does not adress the "SPLIT" word choice, but it is the original statement.

Comment: I think $C_k[i]$ should be the number of entries of $B_k[i-1],B_k[i+1]$ which are at least 2, rather than the number of entries of $C_k[i-1],C_k[i+1]$. Also, you can make everything ternary if in the first case you take $B_k[i] = \min(B_{k-1}[i] + C_{k-1}[i], 2)$.

Comment: It would be great if you could include the original text of the question, so we could verify that you understood it correctly.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I have added the pdf with the problem statement

Comment: The PDF doesn't match your problem statement. If a juggler has three balls then they get to keep one of them.

Comment: Good point, thanks for fixing it. I think it is ok now.